# jqmodal with data-ajax-url not working

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am trying to implement jquery jqmodal at http://communitychessclub.com/test-me.php and am basing my effort on the example at http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/ 2. AJAX, but it doesn't seem to work, nothing happens on click. Also, I don't think #dialog will work because I have more than one game to popup. Any ideas?

```
 <li class="showDialog" id="dialog" data-ajax-url="games/game1256.php">
 <img src="http://d1uzlzehxkwcgj.cloudfront.net/game1256-8.png"></li>

 <script src="js/jqModal-min.js"></script>

 <script>
     $().ready(function(){
         $('#dialog').jqm({
             ajax: '@data-ajax-url', 
             modal: true, 
             trigger: 'li.showDialog'});
         });
     });   
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not incorrect, the `$().ready(handler)` shortcut [is not recommended](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), but it looks like you have a few syntax errors as well:

```
$('#dialog').jqm({
    ajax: '@data-ajax-url', 
    modal: true, 
    trigger: 'li.showDialog'});
});
```

should be written like this:

```
$('#dialog').jqm({
    ajax: '@data-ajax-url', 
    modal: true, 
    trigger: 'li.showDialog'
});
```

You have an extra `});` after `li.showDialog` that should be removed

Comment: With this code (my fault, not yours!) the "modal" pops up in the div (not desired) with the screen grayed and the Chrome browser window frozen. Try clicking the chessboard in the slideshow at  http://communitychessclub.com/test-me.php

Comment: @verlager: I would guess that your AJAX content is not actually being loaded. Additionally, you don't have any type of "close" button for the modal, which gives the window the "frozen" effect you mention.

Comment: I guess simplemodal is another choice and I'm more familiar with it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @verlager: No problem! Good luck with your project!